# How to enable rgb colored output in terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

I'm trying to print a colored string to a gnome-terminal using ANSI escape codes, but, although it works for the custom colors, or even the 256 extra color, it doesn't work with RGB codes.

So, simplifying:

```
cout << "\033[33m" << '.' << "\033[0m"; # prints with color
cout << "\033[38;5;135m" << '.' << "\033[0m"; # prints with color
cout << "\033[38;2;0;135;0m" << '.' << "\033[0m"; # doesn't work, prints with default color
```

How can I output something with an RGB color code in the gnome-terminal?

I'm following this link for outputs: [Wikipedia ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics).

I added:

```
$ export TERM=xterm-256color
```

To my .bashrc file to support 256 colors and:

```
$ tput colors
```

Outputs 256, if that's important.

Comment: You mean the gnome-terminal, bash in an xterm works fine.

Comment: Exactly, edited my question.

Comment: Have a look here, see if this is what you are searching for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682537/ansi-color-specific-rgb-sequence-bash#15712766

Comment: Thanks, but I actually want some way to print, not only with the 256 colors, but the whole RGB range.

Comment: To my knowledge, this cannot be done at this time. The reason for this is that BASH itself cannot specify RGB codes for output color when it directs output to the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RGB colors can not be used in the terminal for these reasons:

- Bash does not choose the commandline colors.
- Bash can only specify ANSI colors.

The two above reasons are very closely linked. Most of these are dependant on your screen and ANSI color specification. If you use a good terminal emulator, you might be able to set custom RGB colors for certain ANSI color codes.

Bash as a shell is powerless as to what the screen can do with displays. It only passes the words on the terminal into your screen. The screen can decide what to do with it. The screen can decide what colors the ANSI escape codes represent (if the terminal even allows colors).

A workaround is to change the terminal color specs. However, very few (I don't know any) will allow you to change colors.

Comment: But [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics) gives an ANSI escape code for rgb colors. Is it wrong and that code is actually invalid?

Comment: @t.pimentel That is the "Extended Set" and is not always allowed in terminals. Also, you need a shell that supports the Extended Set, and very few do (without extreme customization).

Comment: Is there no easy way to make `gnome-terminal` and `bash` work with that Extended Set?

Comment: @t.pimentel Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a way.

Comment: For output of a process (e.g. `ls --color`) directly to terminal, bash is not involved.  Whether the `\033[38;2;0;135;0m` escape sequence works depends on terminal, works for me now on gnome-terminal (well, >5 years passed).  For bash prompt, I believe it again can pass through any string to terminal (except nul character), but it's important to wrap non-printing escape sequences in `\[`...`\]` so its cursor movement is not confused.  E.g. `PS1=$'\[\e[38;2;0;135;0m\][\\u@\\h \\W]\\$\[\e[0m\] '` works for me.

Comment: many terminal allow customizing their 16/256 color pallete.  Some by out-of-band settings, some by escape sequences. 
https://github.com/chriskempson/base16#template-repositories is a good starting point for which ones support applying out-of-band configs, https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell for changing pallete through escape sequences (no terminal list i think, but can try it and see if it worked).

Answer (score 2):

You need vte >= 0.36 for true colors to work in gnome-terminal. Make sure your vte is recent enough, and in that case your code should work.

(Note: when you output hard-coded strings, as you do in your example application, the value of $TERM is necessarily absolutely irrelevant. It only matters if you're using libraries whose behavior depends on this, such as ncurses.)